# While installing firebase-tools, NPM kept on giving dependency warnings despite they have been installed

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

When I'm upgrading my `firebase-tools` from version 8.6.0 to 8.7.0 by running the command `sudo npm i -g firebase-tools` in my functions folder then I get these warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
/.npm/bin/firebase -> /.npm/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
npm WARN ws@7.3.1 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.3.1 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Then I tried to install the dependencies as requested. For example, for the `bufferutil`.
I've tried these two install commands:

```
sudo npm install --save-dev bufferutil@^4.0.1
```

and

```
sudo npm install bufferutil@^4.0.1
```

Which both installs successfully with message like this:

```
> bufferutil@4.0.1 install /_app/functions/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp-build

npm notice save bufferutil is being moved from dependencies to devDependencies
+ bufferutil@4.0.1
updated 1 package in 7.06s

29 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

I also did the same for `utf-8-validate@^5.0.2` and it gave the same success message.

But when I run `firebase deploy --only functions` it tells me again to update to 8.7.0 no matter how many times I run the install command `sudo npm i -g firebase-tools` in the functions folder

```
╭───────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                           │
│      Update available 8.6.0 → 8.7.0       │
│   Run npm i -g firebase-tools to update   │
│                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

So I tried to install the two dependencies again but then it gives the same message as the first one that it requires both the `bufferutil@^4.0.1` and `utf-8-validate@^5.0.2`

I'm not sure what am I missing here. It seems that it doesn't install although already installed.

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.9.1",
    "pg": "^8.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete node_modules folder and execute npm install?

Comment: It gives me `npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE
npm ERR! typeerror Error: Argument #5: Expected object but got string`. Then I did `npm cache clean --force` before deleting it. Then I got  `npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/package.json'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

So apparently the problem happened because I got two firebase executables installed on my computer.
Thus, the firebase I updated is different with the firebase that got executed (because of different paths and different `package.json`).

For me, this happened because I set npm to install firebase dependencies from China mirror servers, which helps a LOT (then I don't need VPN to install firebase dependencies). But I forgot about the two firebase executable thing.
Idk, but you probably could have the same problem caused by other things.

So I fixed the problem like this:

1. Figure out the two `firebase` locations. In my case, it is one in `/opt/local/bin` and another one in `/Users/ME/.npm/bin`. So you could have different location than mine.
2. I checked by doing `firebase --version` in each corresponding directory to see which one has the latest version.
3. Then I deleted the older version and add the `PATH` to the correct firebase in my `.bash_profile`. So I added `export PATH="/Users/ME/.npm/bin"` just before the `export PATH="/opt/local/bin"`

Then restart the terminal or do `source ~/.bash_profile` then it worked!!

Hopefully this could help someone.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful. In my Windows 10. I found C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm> ./firebase.cmd --version to be 9.1.0, and C:\Program Files\nodejs> ./firebase.cmd --version to be 9.10.0 therefore, I needed to remove the one in my AppData\Roaming folder.